# AWK simple line replacement

Tags: awk

How do I get AWK to correctly exchange the values of data file for the string "greater" (than before) or "smaller" (than before)"?

I'm trying:

```
awk '{if ($1>prev); print ($1="greater"); prev="smaller"}' arraydatafile
```

arraydatafile file:

```
 2
 7
 6
 1
 7
 3
```

Desired output:

```
 smaller 
 greater ##### because 7 is greater than previous which is 2 ..
 smaller ##### because 6 is smaller than previous which is 7 .. 
 smaller ##### because 1 is smaller than previous which is 1 ..
 greater ##### etc etc
 smaller
```

I get a jarbled thing instead.

Extremely grateful for your insight on this.

UPDATE:

Theres a new data file for clarification of the task at hand:

arraydatafile:

```
 2
 7
 6
 6
 1
 7
 3
```

desired output

```
 smaller
 greater
 smaller
 equal ##### will remove it later, would be nice if this could be done right from the script or one liner preferrably though
 smaller 
 greater 
 smaller
```

How do I get a one liner that does this in AWK? Its just comparing the previous ones to the next ones and telling what they are in comparison to them. Ill then delete the "equal" output lines with another one liner instead of complicating this little script, in order to simplify the current task at hand.

The script replace.awk:

```
 #!/bin/awk -f
 NR>1 {
 if($1==p){
    # Skip identical lines
    next
 }
 if($1>p){
    print "smaller"
 }else{
    print "greater"
 }
 }

 # Store previous value    
 {p=$1}
```

ran on the arraydatafile

```
  7
  6
  6
  1
  7
  3
```

yields the following

```
 root@debian:/home/user/Documents/# awk -f replace.awk arraydatafile
 smaller
 greater
 greater
 smaller
 greater
```

How do I get the desired output instead?

Comment: Why is 2 (first line) "smaller" ?   What if consecutive lines have equal values?

Comment: Read a line.  Compare the value to the previous line, and output the appropriate string.  Store the line for use on the next iteration.  Repeat.

Comment: What do you want printed if they're both the same value? Put a little thought and effort into your sample input/output and add what you've tried so far and what part of that you need help with.

Comment: 2 is smaller because it is smaller than the next line which is 7.

Comment: if they are both the exact same, I actualy want to remove one of the 2 same ones and compare it to the next.

Comment: 7 is smaller than the next line which is 6 so why does 7 get replaced with greater while 2 gets replaced with smaller? I'd have expected 2 to be replaced with greater since it's greater than the previous line which is null. Really THINK about your requirements and update your question to clearly state what they are with an example that covers **ALL** of your use cases, including the one of consecutive identical values.

Comment: You probably mean `prev=$1`

Comment: you can have first be greater than null or just compare it to the next line, i dont mind

Comment: The answer is probably 42.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
NR>1 {
    if($1==p){
        # Skip identical lines
        next
    }
    if($1>p){
        print "smaller"
    }else{
        print "greater"
    }
}

# Store previous value    
{p=$1}
```

Comment: one liner version available? need working exact code one liner

Comment: Sure. Just put it into one line.

Comment: Phrases guaranteed to stop people from trying to help you: 1) "this doesn't work" and following closely behind is 2) "I need it to be a one liner".